# Allowing use of jQuery in chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have written a Chrome extension which modifies the appearance of an external website (not accessible to me on the server side). The `content.js` file is written in jQuery and it works fine as long as I keep a copy of the jQuery API in the root of the extension's folder, and declare the file's name under `"content_scripts": "matches":` in the extension's  `manifest.json` file. But it shouldn't be necessary to use a local file, should it? Can't I link to `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js` instead? In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519170/using-jquery-with-content-script-and-chrome-extension), it is suggested to add the link under `"content_scripts": "matches":` but that will not work.

I thought this would be a really basic problem and that the answer would be something obvious and heavily upvoted, but I can't find anything like that here. Sorry If it's because I'm thick.

Comment: No. It's a bad idea. Extensions run in privileged context so you need to include the library in the package where it can be verified by Chrome unlike the remote URL that can be hacked remotely or redirected to a malicious server. If you're concerned with the size, consider not using jQuery unless it's more than a few calls.

Comment: OK I see. My `options.js` file also uses jQuery, but here linking to the remote URL is used via modification of the manifest's `content_security_policy` to  `"script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js; object-src 'self'"`. Is that relaxation of the CSP also a bad idea?

Comment: Yes, loading of any external code via relaxed CSP in the privileged context of extensions is a bad idea and Chrome won't allow it in ManifestV3 extensions.

Comment: OK – then the obvious way out is to use the local copy of jquery in that case as well. However, I can't find out how  to tell `options.js` to use the jquery file. I guess it's something in the manifest, or do I have to change something else? I would rather not paste the entire jquery file into `options.js`.

Comment: The options page is a normal html page so just use a `<script>` tag to load jquery.js

Comment: As simple as that... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: Download the library, distribute it within your extension, and use it just like any other script in your extension.**

Reasons:

Loading an external script is a bad idea generally even if it's a well-known library like jQuery.

1. Extensions run in privileged context. The content scripts are severely limited, of course, but still they have messaging access to their background scripts and there could be quite a lot of damage if the remote code was hacked or redirected to a malicious server or proxy.

   - See [Securing your extensions against compromised renderer processes](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-extensions/0ei-UCHNm34/lDaXwQhzBAAJ)
   - See [What bad coding practices makes a browser extension vulnerable?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/34140)
2. Remote code [will be forbidden soon](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nPu6Wy4LWR66EFLeYInl3NzzhHzc-qnk4w4PX-0XMw8/edit#heading=h.7fcrpws74klf) in Manifest V3 extensions, probably in a year or so, and eventually it's likely to be enforced for Manifest V2 extensions as well.
3. Remote code can't be verified by Chrome when it periodically checks the locally installed extensions to ensure their files weren't modified by some malware in the OS or just due to a disk malfunction that resulted in the loss of data/files.
4. Won't work offline if the loaded code was evicted from the browser cache.

Notes:

- If you're concerned with the extension size and there's just a few (dozens of) calls to jQuery, consider not using jQuery at all.
- If you're concerned with automatic updates/fixes applied to jQuery then adopt the more responsible approach: only include an updated library after testing it and ensuring everything works as expected.